# How to run python script on windows startup by setting registry key?

Tags: windows, boot, python, windows-registry

I need to run python with script on windows startup ,I set it in a registry ,

I was using

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"python"="D:\\a\\python\\python.exe"
```

then python is successfully launched ,

but how can i pass the .py file to it ?

I tried

```
"D:\\a\\python\\python.exe" "D:\\a\\python\\main.py"
"D:\\a\\python\\python.exe D:\\a\\python\\main.py"
"start D:\\a\\python\\python.exe D:\\a\\python\\main.py"
```

None of these worked ,I searched a lot through the internet ,didn't find anything useful .

I'm using embedded python, I don't want to add it to the envionrment variables ,I just want to pass .py file to the python.exe and no more .

Comment: I would make a batch file (.bat) and have it read: `"D:\a\python\python.exe" "D:\a\python\main.py"` and then make your run in registry call the .bat file instead.

Comment: @Narzard Yes ,I tried that ,when I double clicked the batch file ,it worked ,when I add it to     the registry ,it doesn't work ,anyways ,I want to do minimal changes to the system ,creating a batch file is not ideal solution .

Comment: Is there a reason to hide it under the run key?  You could either use an LNK (instead of a batch) and put it in your startup folder or use the batch itself.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Tried that ,didn't work on windows 10 ltsc 2019

Comment: If the batch file works, then dropping it into the startup group should also work but yes, I get it.  Keep messing with the registry key.. you will get it.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas it doesn't work, nothing in the shell:startup folder actully starts on boot ,yes ,it SHOULD work ,but it DIDNT work in my case ,i tried with windows 10 ltsc 2019, i tried different application lnks , but no luck ,I can even see it in the task manager startup page, but it didn't start .

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I find out python imports sitecustomize.py by default.

So I actually only have to do two things:

1. Rename my .py file to "sitecustomize.py"
2. Add python or pythonw to the registry.

Python will be launched, and the code will be executed.